# PowerView display on SharePoint 2013 without excel services

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, excel-2013, powerview

I've seen people displaying PowerView reports right on the browser (on SharePoint 2013 pages). So it’s more like a within-screen pop-up (like an element that launches within the page). At the moment, when I create powerView excel sheets, they are displayed as files and when I click on the files, they take me to another page on the browser where Excel Services is launched and people can see both the worksheets and the powerView report. I do not want to go to another page and I don’t want to be able to see the worksheet – just a report, launched cleanly (and still interactive).

Comment: My Question is: what is that technology called that allows me to launch it from within the page - or where I can find more documentation on it. (so I can see how it's done)

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

1. In Excel, there are publishing options that allow you to select which items are visible when viewed via a web part in the browser. So, you can add an Excel services web part to the page, so that users will see just the items you selected.
2. If you have "PowerPivot for SharePoint" installed, you can publish an excel workbook that contains a data model to a "power pivot gallery" (which is a type of library). Once the workbook is in this special type of library, there will be button available that will create a new PowerView report based on the data in that model. This is a slightly different version of PowerView where the design of the reports and viewing of the reports are all done in the browser, not through Excel.

Though, Power View [is being phased out](https://mikesnotebook.wordpress.com/2016/03/04/the-future-of-power-view-and-comparing-data-refresh-options-in-power-bi/), so perhaps check into Power BI?